# How implement 1d covolutional autoencoder for text data in Keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I have bio medical related text data and I want to apply clustering.
Here is my code 
Sequence_len = 58
ebbed_size = 50
I use glove pre trained word vector

```
inputs = Input(shape=(SEQUENCE_LEN, EMBED_SIZE), name="input")

x = Conv1D(filters=NUM_FILTERS, kernel_size=NUM_WORDS,
             activation="relu")(inputs)
x = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=pool_size)(x)
x = Conv1D(filters=12, kernel_size=NUM_WORDS,
             activation="relu")(inputs)
x = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=pool_size)(x)
x = Conv1D(filters=8, kernel_size=NUM_WORDS,
             activation="relu")(x)
encoded = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=pool_size)(x)

x = Conv1D(filters=12, kernel_size=NUM_WORDS,
             activation="relu")(encoded)
x = UpSampling1D(size=pool_size)(x)
x = Conv1D(filters=16, kernel_size=NUM_WORDS,
             activation="relu")(x)
x = UpSampling1D(size=pool_size)(x)
decoded = Conv1D(inputs, kernel_size=NUM_WORDS,
             activation="sigmoid", data_format='channels_first')(x)

autoencoder = Model(inputs, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer="sgd", loss="mse")
```

When I run this code I get this error

```
ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1 for 
'conv1d_37/convolution/Conv2D' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,1,1,8], 
 [1,3,8,12].
```

Comment: What is your `SEQUENCE_LEN`?

Comment: SEQUENCE_LEN = 58 words I already mention above

Comment: And `pool_size`?

Comment: here a full detail 
VOCAB_SIZE = 18610
SEQUENCE_LEN = 58
EMBED_SIZE = 50
BATCH_SIZE = 64
pool_size = 5
NUM_FILTERS = 26
NUM_WORDS = 3
NUM_EPOCHS = 20

Comment: You have a input of length 58. After first pooling - it's 12, after second - it's 3. There is no place for 3rd pooling. Decrease the pooling size or increase sequence length.

Comment: can  I use poo_size = 3 ?

Comment: after pool_size=3
I get this error on last layer TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'data_format'